# running real application on simulated network on omnet++

Tags: omnet++, inet

I was trying to run the showcase given by inet4.4 framework using omnet++ version 6.0.1 and was not able to run it - in showcases -> emulation -> videostreaming.
it is a case of Using Real Applications in a Simulated Network.
if there is someone who succeeded to run it in any version of inet and omnet++, I would like to ask how you did it and which versions did you use , and if
an error like the following came up how can I fix it :

> <!> Error: Cannot assign parameter 'config': xml(): Parse error: Syntax error at string-content:1 -- at /home/ubuntu/Downloads/omnetpp-6.0.1/samples/inet4.4/showcases/emulation/videostreaming/omnetpp.ini:21 -- in module (inet::Ipv4NatTable) VideoStreamingShowcase.router.ipv4.natTable (id=200), during network setup

Answer (score 0):

Its working for me in Omnet6 with Inet 4.3.

```js
*.router.ipv4.natTable.config = xml("<config> \
                                        <entry type='prerouting' \
                                        packetDataFilter='*Ipv4Header and destAddress=~192.168.2.99' \
                                        srcAddress='192.168.3.99' destAddress='192.168.3.20'/> \
                                     </config>")
```

Replace this in your ini file and it should run fine

Comment: what do you mean by replace this ? 
with what ?